# One to 2 characters truncated on right margin of Apple Email messages when printed or saved as PDF

Tags: mail.app, email, pdf, preview, printing

Some Apple mail client email messages truncate 1 to 2 characters on the right of the message when printed or saved as a PDF. Have tested from a Mac with a printer setup and a Mac that has never had an associated printer with equal results. Playing with printer settings has no effect. Suspect the issue is related to invisible formatting in the raw content of the email message. Issue is more likely to be seen when the email content is generated vs sent from a person. For instance the issue is common for receipts generated by online stores.

I've compared the raw email text content of two different generated email messages (one from Apple and one from Audible) where viewing both receipts in email look fine but the printed / PDF output of the Apple receipt looses 1 to 2 characters from the ends of lines approaching the right margin and the Audible receipt looks fine with no missing content in the PDF or printed version. The possible significant difference may be invisible formatting code inside the received message since the Apple email does have embedded control characters (ie. =20 or 20/n) at the ends of the problem lines and the Audible does not.

Can anyone tell me if this issue (in general) is just one of those things NOT related to how I'm set up to receive email, print email, or save email as a PDF but solely dependent on how the message is formatted?

I've spent a good deal of time trying to fix this issue and have come to the conclusion that, in cases where I can't get a faithful version of the email content printed or saved as a PDF, I need to just do a screen print and move on. I've seen this question come up in the Apple user community online but with no helpful answers or even explanations.

Comment: What OS version are you on? I can't say I've seen this problem. Not a fix, but what if you scale to 95% in the print menu before making the PDF? Have you tried a dedicated PDF-to-file print queue, like this: https://github.com/rodyager/RWTS-PDFwriter/tree/master